# Let $( \sqrt{2} + 1)^{1000} = a + b \sqrt{2}$, where a and b are integers. Find the greatest common factor of b and 81.

Tags: number-theory, binomial-theorem

Let $( \sqrt{2} + 1)^{1000} = a + b \sqrt{2}$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers. Find the greatest common factor of $b$ and $81$.
How would one solve this question? I tried to use the binomial theorem but that approach did not work. How would one solve this problem if it were to appear on a Math Olympiad?

I know the answer is one of:

(A) 1 (B) 3 (C) 9 (D) 27 (E) 81.

According to one of the Stack Exchange members, the answer is 3. It was found using Python.

Comment: Ans is 1? @King KONG

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh i do not know

Comment: Simply do exponentiation by repeated squaring, modulo 81?

Comment: Fyi the answer is 3 (found using python)

Comment: @1110101001 are you sure

Comment: This turned out to be harder than I thought.  I figured there'd be a point where all ${1000 \choose 2m+1}$ must be divisible by 81 for all sufficiently large values.  But if that is the case, I'm not seeing it.  I'm pretty sure it is not the case.

Comment: @1110101001 I cannot count that as an answer will this question be marked as unanswered

Comment: @fleablood I tried to find it too

Comment: I wasn't providing a solution — just a answer so others can check their work. And it will take time for proper solutions to pour in. Give it a day or so.

Comment: ok sure @1110101001

Comment: KingKong The correct answer is Q.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a bit annoying, but certainly feasible, to compute the answer by repeated squaring in $(\mathbb{Z}/81\mathbb{Z})[\sqrt{2}]$.

$$(1+\sqrt{2})^2 \equiv 3+2\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^4 \equiv 17+12\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^8 \equiv 10+3\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{16} \equiv 37+60\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{32} \equiv 64+66\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{64} \equiv 10 + 24\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{128} \equiv 37 + 75\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{256} \equiv 64 + 42\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{512} \equiv 10 + 30\sqrt{2}.$$

Now in binary, $1000 = 1111101000_2$, or in other words, $1000 = 512 + 256 + 128 + 64 + 32 + 8.$ Therefore for any $a$
$$a^{1000} = a^{8}a^{32}a^{64}a^{128}a^{256}a^{512},$$
and we can calculate this product for $a=(1+\sqrt{2})$ using the table above:
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{40}\equiv 64+42\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{104}\equiv 64+12\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{232}\equiv 37+60\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{488}\equiv 37+48\sqrt{2}$$
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^{1000}\equiv 10+51\sqrt{2}$$
and $(51,81)=3.$

Comment: One interesting thing I noted is that if you compute $b$ for the first few powers of $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ you get $1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70$ which seems to fit a fibonacci polynomial $F_x(2)$. And so the value of b for n=1000 is equal to $2*F_{999}(2) + F_{998}(2)$. I don't know if this is useful though.

Comment: I do not understand why (1+sqrt(2)^104 < (1+sqrt(2)^40. @user7530

Comment: @KingKONG He's working modulo 81

Comment: @1110101001 I do not know how to work modulo 81 can you explain the logic to me. Sorry I am only in 10th grade and we haven't come across this topic in detail.

Comment: @KingKONG http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Modular_arithmetic/Introduction

Comment: how were the values for the large exponents calculated. why is the base 2

Comment: notation of 1000. Can you explain this in a little more detail @user7530

Comment: @1110101001 can you explain it in more detail

Comment: @KingKONG Values were computed by hand via exponentiation by squaring (numbers don't get too big since you always take mod 81). Use binary to find how to combine the powers of two in exponents to get an exponent of 1000.

Answer (score 5):

This is so long for a comment:

We say $ ( \sqrt{2} + 1)^{n} = a_n + b_n \sqrt{2}$ and $a_n,b_n$ are integers. Therefore $( 1- \sqrt{2})^{n} = a_n - b_n \sqrt{2}$. For positive odd value of $n=2k-1$, by product

$-1=( \sqrt{2} + 1)^{n} ( 1- \sqrt{2} )^{n}= (a_n + b_n \sqrt{2})(a_n - b_n \sqrt{2})$.

Hence $a_n^2 - 2b_n^2= -1$. $a^2-2b^2=-1$ is negative Pell equation and minimal solution is $(a_1,b_1)=(1,1)$. Other solutions: $a_{n+2}+b_{n+2}\sqrt 2= (a_n + b_n \sqrt 2)\cdot (1+\sqrt 2)^2$ and then

$$a_{n+2}= 3a_n + 4b_n$$ $$ b_{n+2} = 2a_n + 3b_b$$

For example $(a_3,b_3)=(7,5)$. So, $$a_{n+2} \equiv b_n \pmod{3}$$ $$b_{n+2} \equiv 2a_n \equiv 2b_{n-2}\pmod{3}$$

Since $b_1=1$ is not divisible by $3$, then for all odd $n$, $b_n$ is not divisible by $3$. Similarly, $a_n$ is not divisible by $3$.

In $ ( \sqrt{2} + 1)^{999} = a_{999} + b_{999} \sqrt{2}$, $a_{999}$ and $b_{999}$ can't divisible by $3$. Yet, I didn't say anything about $b_{1000}$. I will think about even values of $n$.

Comment: I also found experimentally that $b_{n+1}$ = $2*b_n + b_{n-1}$

Answer (score 4):

I found a very fast solution with using linear reccurence relations.

Let's say $( \sqrt{2} + 1)^{n} = a_n + b_n \sqrt{2}$. Here $n\ge 1$ and $a_n,b_n,n$ are positive integers. Then $( - \sqrt{2} + 1)^{n} = a_n - b_n \sqrt{2}$. Hence

$$b_n = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt2} \left[ ( 1+\sqrt{2})^{n} - ( 1-\sqrt{2})^{n} \right] \tag{1}$$

By $(1)$, $b_1=1$ and $b_2=2$. Now, we can write characteristic polynomial of $b_n$. By $(1)$, roots of the characteristic polynomial are $r_1=1+\sqrt{2}$ and $r_2=1-\sqrt{2}$. Therefore characteristic polynomial for $b_n$ is

$$r^2-2r-1=0 \tag{2}$$

and we find

$$b_{n+2}=2b_{n+1}+b_n \tag{3}$$

Let's examine the terms of $b_n$ in $\mod 9$.

$b_1 \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$, $b_2 \equiv 2 \pmod{9}$ . We have to find smallest positive $m$ integer such that $b_{m+1}=1$ and $b_{m+2}=2$. Let's search it:

$b_3 = 2b_2+b_1 \equiv 5 \pmod{9}$, $b_4 = 2b_3+b_2 \equiv 3 \pmod{9}$, $b_5 \equiv 2 \pmod{9}$, $b_6 \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$, $b_7 \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$, $b_8 \equiv 3 \pmod{9}$, $b_9 \equiv 4 \pmod{9}$, $b_{10} \equiv 2 \pmod{9}$, $b_{11} \equiv 8 \pmod{9}$,  $b_{12} \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$, $b_{13} \equiv 8 \pmod{9}$,  $b_{14} \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$, $b_{15} \equiv 4 \pmod{9}$, $b_{16} \equiv 6 \pmod{9}$, $b_{17} \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$, $b_{18} \equiv 2 \pmod{9}$, $b_{19} \equiv 2 \pmod{9}$, $b_{20} \equiv 6 \pmod{9}$, $b_{21} \equiv 5 \pmod{9}$, $b_{22} \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$, $b_{23} \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$, $b_{24} \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$.

Now $b_{25} \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$ and $b_{26} \equiv 2 \pmod{9}$. Therefore $b_n$ is periodic in $\mod 9$ and period of it is $m=24$. Thus $1000 \equiv 16 \pmod{24}$ and

$$b_{1000} \equiv b_{16} \equiv 6 \pmod{9}$$

Hence $3 \mid b_{1000}$ but $9 \not\mid b_{1000}$. Finally $\gcd(81,b_{1000})=3$.

**Note:** This method is very powerful. An example, $n=1234567890$ and $n\equiv 18 \pmod{24}$. Thus $b_{1234567890}\equiv b_{18}\equiv 2 \pmod{9}$ and $3 \not\mid b_{1234567890}$. (For clearness, I wrote details of solution. My manual solution is short and it in the picture.)

[image: reccurence]